# Evaluate Bool property of optional object in if statement

Tags: swift, boolean, evaluation, option-type

I am looking for a way to evaluate a Swift `Bool` concisely in a single `if` statement, when the `Bool` is the property of an optional object:

```
var objectWithBool: ClassWithBool?
// ...

if let obj = objectWithBool {
    if obj.bool {
        // bool == true
    } else {
        // bool == false
    }
} else {
    // objectWithBool == nil
}
```

Is there are way to combine these `if` statements? In Objective-C this could easily be done, as a `nil` object can be evaluated in the same expression:

```
if (objectWithBool.bool) {
    // bool == true
} else {
    // bool == false || objectWithBool == nil
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ah, found it:

```
if objectWithBool?.bool == true {
    // objectWithBool != nil && bool == true
} else {
    // objectWithBool == nil || bool == false
}
```

The optional chaining expression `objectWithBool?.bool` returns an optional `Bool`. Since it is optional, that expression alone in the `if` statement would be evaluated to `true`/`false` based on whether the optional contains a value or not.

By using the `==` operator the `if` statement checks the optional's value, which in this case can be `true`, `false`, or `nil`.

Comment: I would not say that it *"forces the optional Bool to be evaluated"*. `objectWithBool?.bool` can be `true`, `false` or `nil` (`== Optional<Bool>.None`), and the comparison `== true` yields `true` only in the first case.

Comment: @MartinR True, I was a bit hasty there. I've expanded the explanation a bit - hopefully it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution is:

```
if objectWithBool?.bool ?? false {
    println("objectWithBool != nil && objectWithBool.bool == true")
} else {
    println("objectWithBool == nil || objectWithBool.bool == false")
}
```

The ["nil coalescing operator"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_123) `a ?? b`
is a shorthand for

```
a != nil ? a! : b
```

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. I like the nil coalescing operator, it can produce some really neat code. I'd argue that here it's slightly less clear than checking for equality with `true`, since at a glance the presence of `false` might look like the logic is the other way around. Good idea though!

Comment: @Stuart: That depends on how you look at it. Coming from (plain) C, I prefer `if boolVar {}` to `if boolVar == true {}` and then `?? false` acts as a default value. And it works similarly for other types, for example `if (myArray?.count ?? 0) > 0`. – So it is just a matter of personal preference :)

Comment: You're right, and I also prefer `if boolVar {}` where possible. I suppose I mean it could be confusing in the naïve sense that at a glance one might mistakenly think the expression is checking for _equality_ with `false`. I'll probably change my mind when I get more accustomed to reading the `??` operator :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do :

```
if let obj = objectWithBool where obj {
    // objectWithBool != nil && obj == true
} else {
   // objectWithBool == nil || obj == false
}
```

Comment: This is useful if you need to use the unwrapped `Bool` inside the `if` block, otherwise you should discard the variable with `if let _ = objectWithBool ...`, or use one of the other answers. Also, note that in Swift 3 the syntax has changed to `if let obj = objectWithBool, obj { ... } else { ... }`