# How do you inspect an Optional-String's length?

Tags: string, swift, option-type

```
class PersonEntry: NSObject {
  var firstName: String?
  var lastName: String?
}

//This errors
if (self.person.firstName?.isEmpty) {
          println("Empty")
}

//Compiler auto-correction is this
if ((self.model.firstName?.isEmpty) != nil) {
          println("Empty")
}
```

I understand that optional chaining returns an optional type. So I suppose my question is, how do you unwrap an optional string, to inspect it's length, without risking a crash ?

Comment: Similar question (with two different solutions) here: [Evaluate Bool property of optional object in if statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910229/evaluate-bool-property-of-optional-object-in-if-statement).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I presume that if the property is nil then you want to consider it empty - in that case you can use the nil coalescing operator in combination with the first version of the if statement:

```
if self.person.firstName?.isEmpty ?? true {
          println("Empty")
}
```

If `firstName` is nil, the expression evaluates to the right side of the coalescing operator, `true` - otherwise it evaluates to the value of the `isEmpty` property.

---

References:

[Nil Coalescing Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72)

[Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245)

Comment: thanks Antonio. do you know a good link for reading up on this particular syntax. i would like to read around it.

Comment: @robdashnash: added links to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Another trick.

```
var str: String?
str = "Hello, playground"

println(count(str ?? ""))
```