# Unwrap value and verify it's content on the same line with swift

Tags: swift

pushIsActivated is an optional bool variable. I use this code to check it's value

```
if let pushOn = pushIsActivated {
    if pushOn {
        // Do some stuff...
    }
}
```

is it possible to do something like

```
if let pushOn = pushIsActivated, pushOn {
    // Do some stuff ...
}
```

Or

```
if let pushOn = pushIsActivated && pushOn {
    // Do some stuff ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly as you wrote it in the second code block (Swift 3)... Did you try it?

Comment: What is the deep sense of an **optional** `Bool`?

Comment: @vadian: It could be the result of a dictionary lookup or optional chaining.

Comment: Related: [Evaluate Bool property of optional object in if statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910229/evaluate-bool-property-of-optional-object-in-if-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line should be:

```
if let pushOn = pushIsActivated where pushOn {

}
```

Comment: You''re using deprecated Swift 2 syntax, while the question gives an example with a newer Swift 3 syntax.

Comment: I am using swift 2 and not 3, the syntax in the question was not working for me that's why I asked it. This syntax is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

Sure! Check this simple example:

```
var testBool: Bool?
    testBool = true
    if let unwrappedTestBool = testBool, unwrappedTestBool {
        print("Success")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is!

```
var aVal: Bool?

aVal = true
if let aVal = aVal, aVal {
    print(aVal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check both the values in a single `if` condition like this

```
if let pushOn = pushIsActivated, let pushOn1 = anotherCondition {
// Do some stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I usually compare to true in these cases

```
if pushIsActive == true {
    // Run when pushIsActive is true
} else {
    // Run when pushIsActive is nil or false
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to get comments on why this is being down voted. This will give the exact result at the accepted answer, but with less code.